# 404 not found during Spring Websocket using sockJS and Stomp

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am getting the error mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279090/error-opening-websocket-connection-using-spring-4) question, exactly the same. I found other solutions, but they consider an xml configuration. The solution is provided in the above question as well, but what exactly is supposed to be added to the AppConfig.java file according to the answer?

Comment: could you please elaborate your error message.Some code will also be helpful

Comment: the error is the same as in the above link I have given. It is exactly the same. Just that I dont know how to implement the solution provided in it. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: you are using xml configuration or Java configuration

Comment: java configuration. I have WebConfig.java, WebSocketConfig.java, Application.java and SecurityConfig.java... I will post the files in an edit soon.. In some time..

Comment: the issue in given link is that the configuration file was not accessible to container as  it was into in the componentscan(@ComponentScan) path..

Comment: So what should I change and where should I change, in order to get it working?

Comment: For that please share configuration code

Comment: Is your problem solved.